# Running multiple app instances on a single container in PCF

Tags: cloud-foundry

We have an internal installation of PCF.
A developer wants to push a stateless (obeys 12 factor rules) nodejs app which will spawn other app instances i.e leverage nodejs clustering as per https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html. Hence there would be multiple processes running on each container. Any known issues with this from a PCF perspective? I appreciate it violates the rule/suggestion of one app instance per container but that is just a suggestion :) All info welcome.
Regards
John

Answer (score 1):

When running an application on Cloud Foundry that spawns child processes, the number one thing you need to watch out for is memory consumption.  You set a memory limit when you push your application which is for the entire container.  That includes the parent process, whatever child processes are spawned and a little overhead (currently init process, sshd process & health check).

Why is this a problem?  Most buildpacks make the assumption that only one process will be running and that it will consume as much memory as possible while staying under the defined memory limit.  They attempt to configure the software which is running your application to do this.  When you spawn child processes, this breaks the buildpack's assumptions and can create scenarios where your application will exceed the defined memory limit.  When this happens, even by one byte, the process will be killed and restarted.

If you're concerned with scaling your application, you should not try to spin off child processes in one extra large container.  Instead, let the platform help you and scale up the number of application instances.  The platform can easily do this and by using multiple smaller containers you can scale just as well.  In fact, if you already have a 12-factor app, it should be well positioned to work in this manner.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the info. The reason given for the 'one extra large container' is cost. Our internal costing for the use of PCF is based on number of instances; the more instances used the greater the cost. The developer is basically looking to reduce the cost, I'm looking for good reasons why he can't use a small number of 'containers stuffed with processes' . Thanks again.

Comment: Ultimately, there will be a ceiling to which you can scale the app by making a larger container.  The larger the memory goes, the harder it will be for the platform to find a Cell with free memory.  Think about it, if you need an 8G memory limit and you have 16G Cells, this app can only be placed on Cells with more than 50% of their memory free.  Aside from that, there are limits which cannot go up, like the number of open files.  There's a fixed limit per container, and while it's pretty large, you will eventually bump into this since network connections are treated as files on Linux.

Comment: You as an operator could also utilize quotas to put lower ceilings on the memory.  With quotas, you can put a lower ceiling on the max memory a single app instance can consume.  For example, you could make it so that 4G is the max one app instance can request.   See `cf create-quota -h`.

Comment: Aside from that, you have the argument for HA.  More app instances provides you with better HA.  https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/prepare-to-deploy.html#increase-availability

Comment: Thanks for all info. HA is covered as they must deploy a number of containers> 1. They just to deploy as small as number as possible and stuff app instances into them :)